# How to reset arguments inside a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, arguments

I have an activity with a tab layout that hosts 4 fragments but one at a time. The fragment displays user stats for different games. To begin with the user selects a username from a recycler view in an activity. This displays the users stats for game1. The user is then able to press a next button that shows the stats for the next player and so on. However, when the user slides the tab-layout I want the stats for game two to show the stats for the player that they were currently looking at in game one but instead the fragment is using the original arguments i.e. the user name they selected at the beginning in the recycler view.

I am using an adapter that is called at the beginning and whenever the user swipes the tab layout:

```
   public void setName (String name ) {
    nameToFind = name;
}

@Override public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position){


        case 0:
            ViewGameOneStatsFragment gameOneStatsFragment = new ViewGameOneStatsFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString("nameToFind", nameToFind);
            gameOneStatsFragment.setArguments(args);
            return gameOneStatsFragment;
        case 1:
            ViewGameTwoStatsFragment gameTwoStatsFragment = new ViewGameTwoStatsFragment();
            Bundle argsgameTwo = new Bundle();
            argsgameTwo.putString("nameToFind", nameToFind);
            gameTwoStatsFragment.setArguments(argsgameTwo);
            return gameTwoStatsFragment;
        case 2:
            ViewGameThreeStatsFragment gameThreeStatsFragment = new ViewGameThreeStatsFragment();
            Bundle argsgameThree = new Bundle();
            argsgameThree.putString("nameToFind", nameToFind);
            gameThreeStatsFragment.setArguments(argsgameThree);
            return gameThreeStatsFragment;

        case 3:
            ViewGameFourStatsFragment gameFourStatsFragment = new ViewGameFourStatsFragment();
            Bundle argsgameFour = new Bundle();
            argsgameFour.putString("nameToFind", nameToFind);
            gameFourStatsFragment.setArguments(argsgameFour);
            return gameFourStatsFragment;
    }
    return null;
}
```

I tried creating an instance of the adapter class to reset the `nameToFind` but I was unable to as its constructor needs a fragment manager which I am unable to get within the fragment `getSupportFragmentManager()` isn't an option.

Here is one of the fragments retrieving the arguments in the onCreate method

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    assert getArguments() != null;
    this.mUser = getArguments().getString("nameToFind");
    //OnCreateView is then called.

}
```

What options do I have?

Comment: Why are you sending the same arguments to all 4 fragments?

Comment: Using a static variable instead  of arguements would do the trick , not the cleanest way though

Comment: @AhmadSattout because this string is the primary key that a db uses to look up other stats.

Comment: If all the fragments use the same arguments, either make them inside the Activity's intent, or save them in some shared preferences maybe. Still, that doesn't explain why you want to reset the arguments? it's `setArguments(null)` if that's what you want

Comment: It sounds like you need a listener to pass data around!